# How to get instance in this array result from Query in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of results from a query in a variable called `$result`

Here is a `var_dump()` of this variable:

http://pastebin.com/pc53Pmgf

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (25) {
    ["procedure_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["patient_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["department_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dosage_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["edocument"]=>
    string(10) "Bruce1.jpg"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(8) "02:26:00"
    ["submitted"]=>
    string(19) "2011-07-31 19:56:29"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["patient_age"]=>
    string(2) "34"
    ["patient_height"]=>
    string(4) "1.34"
    ["patient_weight"]=>
    string(2) "45"
    ["patient_gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Cardiology"
    ["procedure_name_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["procedure_name"]=>
    string(5) "IVH 2"
    ["procedure_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["dosage_emitted"]=>
    NULL
    ["dosage_absorbed"]=>
    NULL
    ["dosage_period"]=>
    NULL
    ["event_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["time"]=>
    string(8) "12:34:00"
    ["success"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
    ["event"]=>
    string(5) "start"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#24 (25) {
    ["procedure_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["patient_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["department_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dosage_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["edocument"]=>
    string(10) "Bruce1.jpg"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(8) "02:26:00"
    ["submitted"]=>
    string(19) "2011-07-31 19:56:29"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["patient_age"]=>
    string(2) "34"
    ["patient_height"]=>
    string(4) "1.34"
    ["patient_weight"]=>
    string(2) "45"
    ["patient_gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Cardiology"
    ["procedure_name_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["procedure_name"]=>
    string(5) "IVH 2"
    ["procedure_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["dosage_emitted"]=>
    NULL
    ["dosage_absorbed"]=>
    NULL
    ["dosage_period"]=>
    NULL
    ["event_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["time"]=>
    string(8) "14:50:00"
    ["success"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
    ["event"]=>
    string(3) "sds"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (25) {
    ["procedure_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["patient_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["department_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["dosage_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["edocument"]=>
    string(10) "Bruce1.jpg"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["duration"]=>
    string(8) "02:26:00"
    ["submitted"]=>
    string(19) "2011-07-31 19:56:29"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["patient_age"]=>
    string(2) "34"
    ["patient_height"]=>
    string(4) "1.34"
    ["patient_weight"]=>
    string(2) "45"
    ["patient_gender"]=>
    string(4) "Male"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Cardiology"
    ["procedure_name_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["procedure_name"]=>
    string(5) "IVH 2"
    ["procedure_description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["dosage_emitted"]=>
    NULL
    ["dosage_absorbed"]=>
    NULL
    ["dosage_period"]=>
    NULL
    ["event_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["time"]=>
    string(8) "15:00:00"
    ["success"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
    ["event"]=>
    string(3) "end"
  }
}
```

I want to access the instance ["dosage_id"]. How would I write the code to this>

I tried all these:

```
$result["dosage_id"];
$result[0]["dosage_id"];
$result->"dosage_id";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array results are objects, as

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#23 (25) {
```

details. Since this class has public properties, `$result[0]->dosage_id` will retrieve the `dosage_id` property value of the first object.

Comment: In this case, the object is an instance of StdClass, so its properties would be public by default

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
$result[0]->dosage_id
```

`$result[0]` is an object, and its properties you access with `->`

Comment: @sqlmole: PHP doesn't have pointers. `->` was chosen because `.` is used for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$result[0]->dosage_id;`